# Maya Python mass .obj import how to turn off obj import warning?

Tags: python, maya

Hey I am importing a list of files into a maya scene via python.

Each time a .obj is imported maya gives me following warning:

```
Warning: Option "Use legacy vertex order" will only take effect when option "Multiple Objects" is enabled.
```

My question: Is it possible to turn off this warning? Or a way to to not show the warning in the first place?

edit: The problem is that this warning will show up on each and every file that gets imported from the list. I added a screenshot from maya.

[image]

I am loading the files like this:

```
cmds.file(filePath, i = True)
```

edit2: Here is my function that loops through files in a directory.

```
def loadFiles(*args):
# load References into scene from savefile

files = 'c:/testfolder'

if os.path.exists(files):

    filesInFolder = [f for f in listdir(files) if isfile(join(files, f))]

    for file in filesInFolder:

        filePath = files + '/' + file
        #cmds.file(filePath, i = True)
        mel.eval("catchQuiet(`python(\"cmds.file(filePath, i=True)\")`)")

        #print filePath
```

Thank you for your time and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maya has a function called `catchQuiet` which is the easiest way of suppressing warning/error messages. If the expression throws an error, it will return `1` otherwise `0`.

```
catchQuiet(python("cmds.file(\"/drive/myfile.obj\", i=True)"))
```

Unfortunately this function does only exist in `mel` but you could wrap it in python by using `maya.cmds.mel` to execute it.

> Python Wrapper

The Python variant looks a little nasty, but that should work.

```
mel.eval("catchQuiet(`python(\"cmds.file('/drive/myfile.obj', i=1)\")`)")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes in MEL i would have used that. But sadly i dont really know how to wrap this command into python. Could you give me a complete example?

Comment: Added the python wrapper as well

Comment: Thank you but this not work for me. It does not import my files.

Comment: Is it returning `0` or `1` for you?

Comment: Nothing when I use it within my code. When I paste it into the scripteditor it returns 1L. I´ll edit my post with my code, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to turn off errors, warnings, and info in Script Editor:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

filePath="/Users/swift/Desktop/file.ma"
cmds.file(filePath,i=True)

cmds.scriptEditorInfo(suppressErrors=True)
cmds.scriptEditorInfo(suppressWarnings=True)
cmds.scriptEditorInfo(suppressInfo=True)
```

or try this method just for warnings:

```
cmds.warning()
print '',
```

Then, turn them on again:

```
cmds.scriptEditorInfo(se=False,sw=False,si=False)
```

Comment: Even though that this might be a solution, turning off warnings is a bad practice.

Comment: This did not work for me @andy.
I know that this is a bad practice but a file importer to save time while importing multiple files is not really time-saving when this error accures.